# python- subprocess not streaming the live output correctly on command window

Tags: python

I have a python GUI in which I have attached command window and also having thread process running in background window.

The statement for running one python file from the main page is below:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "c:\files\sample.py"], cwd=cwd, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)


for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
        self.output.write(line)
```

Here the output is not streaming as live in the command window.Instead it is printing the output as whole.

Also when running the file the command window went to 'Not responding' state.It may be because the sample.py has more content.Not sure.

Can you tell me how to print the running content of sample.py in command window?

I have tried so many methods which was posted in stackoverflow,but still the same result.

Comment: check `bufsize` argument in the documentation; remove second 'read'; "finished..." this should be outside the loop

Comment: `bufsize` is zero..sry.typing mistake.Those two statements are out of loop only.

Comment: @Jerzyk,we need to set `bufsize` for proper live update?

Comment: you are reading one by one in the loop, then you are trying to (possibly) read again from a closed pipe, I've told you - remove second read

Comment: @Jerzyk,I have removed and tried again.but same issue.It is printing as whole and window is in 'not responding' state before printing.

Comment: @Jerzyk,if the window is in normal,subprocess working properly.I dont know sometime the window went 'non responding' state while running subprocess.In the time output printing as whole.

Comment: This reading is done in separate thread?

Comment: No..but the python GUI has thread running in background.Not for this process

Comment: so, maybe put this is separate thread, then? :)

Comment: I did not get you actually.you want me to put these subprocess statements in thread file?

Comment: @Jerzyk, i have tried to put this in thread.But got same results.No Change in behavior.